# locator equation of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, greens-functions, tight-binding

I strugle with folowing problem. I do start with the locator equation of motion:

$$G_{i j} = g_i \delta_{i j} + g_i \sum\limits_{k \ne i} W_{i k} G_{k j}$$

where $G_{i j}$ are matrix elements of Green function in a site representation, $W_{i k}$ is some of diagonal matrix.

For the purpose of the problem it is said: $g_i = g$, and $W_{i k}$ depends only on the distance between sites i and j. The above equation is multiplied by $e^{i(\mathbf{k R_i - k' R_j})}$ and summed over i and j, giving:

$$G(E;\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k'})=g\delta_{\mathbf{k}\mathbf{k'}} + g \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{i j k \ne i} W_{i k} G_{k j} e^{i(\mathbf{k R_i - k' R_j})}$$

That being said, now I encountered the sentence "Since $W_{i k}$ is translationally invariant, we introduce Fourier transform in the usual way and we can write"

$$G(E;\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k'})=g\delta_{\mathbf{k}\mathbf{k'}} + g W(\mathbf{k}) G(E;\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k'}) $$

And this is where is my problem, how did that last happened, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$W_{ik}$ is translationally invariant" means
$$
W_{ik} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{\bf{q}}{W(\bf{q})e^{-i\bf{q}\cdot\left(\bf{R}_i - \bf{R}_k \right)}}
$$
possibly with 
$$
\sum_{\bf{q}}{W(\bf{q})} = 0
$$
if $W_{ii}=0$ is explicitly defined. Substitute in the sum defining $G(E;\bf{k}, \bf{k}')$,
$$
\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{ijk\neq i}{\sum_{\bf{q}}W({\bf q})G_{kj}e^{i\left(\bf{k}\cdot\bf{R}_i-\bf{k}'\cdot\bf{R}_j \right)}e^{-i\bf{q}\cdot\left(\bf{R}_i - \bf{R}_k \right)}}
$$
notice that the sum over $i$ now amounts to 
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i\neq k}{e^{i\left(\bf{k} -\bf{q} \right)\cdot{\bf R}_i}} = \delta({\bf k} -{\bf q}) - \frac{1}{N}e^{i\left(\bf{k} -\bf{q} \right)\cdot{\bf R}_k}
$$
and collapse the original sum to
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{jk}{W({\bf k})G_{kj}e^{i\left(\bf{k}\cdot\bf{R}_k-\bf{k}'\cdot\bf{R}_j \right)}} - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{jk}{\sum_{{\bf q}}{W({\bf q})}G_{kj}e^{i\left(\bf{k}\cdot\bf{R}_k-\bf{k}'\cdot\bf{R}_j \right)}}
$$
etc.